# For looping in C confused

Tags: c, loops

What problem if I use `strlen()` in the condtion of for loop.

```
    char s[i];
    for (int i = 0; strlen(s); i++)
```

So if I use upper code there took a lot of time.
But if I store the value of `strlen` of `s` it took little time inspect to upper code.

What difference between these?

Comment: You need to post what the loop does to modify `s`. If it changes its length to `0`, the loop will end. If it doesn't it is infinite. It's undefined behaviour anyway, since `s` is uninitialised.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)

Comment: Why are you using `i` to define the length of the string , and to control the loop? It's a different `i`. Please use sensibly implemented and sensibly named variables.

Comment: Assuming this is not just a contrived example of your code, you're not initializing s[] to anything.  You set it to some unknown length, i, but did not initialize it with a string. So, each time you run it, strlen() is going to give you different results, because it scans memory starting at 's' until it hits a \0 character. Sometimes it will be close to the start of the array, others, not so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `i < strlen(s)` as a condition because the length of the string in `s` gets recomputed for each iteration of the loop.  It is better to use a separate variable and compute the length in the initialization part:

```
for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Note that your definition of `s` looks like a typo: `char s[i];`. What variable `i` are you referring to? what would be its value before the beginning of the `for` loop that defines a new `i` variable?

**EDIT**

After reformatting your code, I realized there is even more confusion:

```
for (int i = 0; strlen(s); i++)
```

This `for` loops iterates as long as string `s` is not empty. Is this your intent? Do you modify `s` inside the loop? `s` is uninitialized, the test invokes undefined behavior. Do you initialize `s` in code you did not post between the definition and the `for` loop? If you do, it would still be more efficient to write such a loop this way:

```
for (int i = 0; *s != '\0'; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is evaluated before every iteration of the loop.

C strings are just an array of characters, then a `NULL`. So to work out the length you have to start at the start and inspect every character from there until you find the `NULL`.

So in complexity terms, strlen is O(n). Your for is also O(n). If you check the `strlen` every time then your implementation is O(n*n). If you work it out once in adavance then yours os O(n). Try it with longer `s`s to see a much bigger difference.